# Composing Java 8 method references in stream collector

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference, collectors

I would like to compose method references in a stream's collect(Collectors.toMap(..)) call. In the following example, I have code that accomplishes my task without a method reference:

```
class A {
    private String property1;
    private B property2;

    public String getProperty1() { return property1; }
    public B getProperty2() { return property2; }
}

class B {
    private String property3;

    public String getProperty3() { return property3; }
}

public class Main {
    public static void Main() {
        List<A> listOfA = /* get list */;

        Map<String, String> = listOfA.stream()
            .collect(toMap(x -> x.getProperty1(), x -> x.getProperty2().getProperty3()));
    } 
}
```

It is trivial to change `x -> x.getProperty1()` to `A::getProperty1()`. However it is not as trivial with `x -> x.getProperty2().getProperty3()`. I would like one of the following to work:

```
.collect(toMap(A::getProperty1, ((Function)A::getProperty2).andThen((Function)B::getProperty3)))
```

or

```
.collect(toMap(A::getProperty1, ((Function)B::getProperty3).compose((Function)A::getProperty2)))
```

However, they both give me the error `Non-static method cannot be referenced from static context`.

Comment: There isn't going to be a better way to do this.  The original lambda is the best you're going to get.

Comment: Every answer you'll end up with are going to be longer, clunkier and more unreadeable than the lambda expression. Why do you want to use another way?

Comment: I am mostly exploring this out of curiosity, at least in this particular formulation of the question. Even the two examples I provided (which do not work) are clunkier and less readable than the lambda. However, method composition is a powerful feature that I would use more often if I could. If either of you could explain why this is not allowed, and additionally in which cases I can use method composition (for example, if all of the methods were static, would it be possible?), that would be extremely useful and worth an accepted answer in my opinion. Thanks either way!

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be _any_ cases where it was doable without a cast.  The problem is that `A::getProperty2` could be _any_ functional interface with an `andThen` method that happened to return a `java.util.function.Function`, and Java can't infer that for you.

Comment: Method references are a shorthand for a very restricted set of lambdas.  Everyone, on first encounter with them, wants to find ways to extend them to cover more cases (chaining, binding parameters, etc) -- but once you get past just naming a method, the benefit isn't there, so that's where the shorthand stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A::getProperty2` is a `Function<A, B>` (that is a Function that takes an instance of A and returns an instance of B).

You can cast and compose it as:

```
((Function<A, B>)A::getProperty2).andThen(B::getProperty3)
```

Or you can create a Function producer like:

```
public static <A, B, R> Function<A, R> compose(
        Function<A, B> f1, Function<B, R> f2) {
    return f1.andThen(f2);
}
```

And use it to compose as:

```
compose(A::getProperty2, B::getProperty3)
```

Comment: `A::getProperty2` is a valid method reference for a `Function`, it cannot be used as a `Supplier` at all, as it takes a parameter of type `A`.

Comment: So my mistake was casting it to `Function` instead of `Function<A,B>` as you clarified. Thanks!